# UBUNTU 20.04 Pi-hole, lighttpd service not running

Tags: networking, 20.04, lighttpd

Hope someone can help me with "pi-hole" installation over single board computer:

- **UBUNTU 20.04**
- **Rpi4-8GB/64 bit 1.4 firmware version**.

I followed the basic links (installation should be very easy):

[ed-install](https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole/#one)
and
[install PI hole](https://linuxincluded.com/install-pi-hole-on-ubuntu/)
and
[watched](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QzHriM9B_c)
(It is same procedure, regardless the version).

My problem is that everything gets "stuck" at this point:

```
*[✓] Detected ARM-aarch64 architecture
[i] Checking for existing FTL binary...
[i] Latest FTL Binary already installed (v5.0). Confirming Checksum...
[i] Checksum correct. No need to download!
usermod: user 'pihole' does not exist
grep: /etc/pihole/setupVars.conf: No such file or directory
[i] Testing if systemd-resolved is enabled
[i] Systemd-resolved does not need to be restarted
[i] Restarting lighttpd service...ubuntu@ubuntu-server:~$ ^C*
```

So I never get any status for "**completed installation**" and not possible to access pi-hole web interface or do anything else **including uninstall**. It looks like process has been finished but...nothing there.

I tried a lot of suggestions regarding "**lighttpd service**" but none of mentioned worked:

- [Stuck on installation restarting lighttpd service](https://www.reddit.com/r/pihole/comments/c4u8bf/stuck_on_installation_restarting_lighttpd_service/) in reddit.
- [PI hole no web interface access and lighttpd service failed to start](https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/pi-hole-no-web-interface-access-and-lighttpd-service-failed-to-start/14225/34)
  in discourse.
- [PI hole](https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole/issues/576) issues in github.

My typical code when I run the install command from terminal (it seems to work, but nothing installed..or concluded...The system just stops...):

```
*ubuntu@ubuntu-server:~$ sudo curl -sSL https://install.pi-hole.net | bash
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu-server: Name or service not known
[✗] Root user check
Script called with non-root privileges
The Pi-hole requires elevated privileges to install and run
Please check the installer for any concerns regarding this requirement
Make sure to download this script from a trusted source
[✓] Sudo utility check
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu-server: Name or service not known
[✓] Root user check
.;;,.
.ccccc:,.
:cccclll:. ..,,
:ccccclll. ;ooodc
'ccll:;ll .oooodc
.;cll.;;looo:.
.. ','.
.',,,,,,'.
.',,,,,,,,,,.
.',,,,,,,,,,,,....
....''',,,,,,,'.......
......... .... .........
.......... ..........
.......... ..........
......... .... .........
........,,,,,,,'......
....',,,,,,,,,,,,.
.',,,,,,,,,'.
.',,,,,,'.
..'''.
Existing PHP installation detected : PHP version 7.4.3
[✓] Disk space check
[✓] Update local cache of available packages
[✓] Checking apt-get for upgraded packages... 11 updates available
It is recommended to update your OS after installing the Pi-hole!
Installer Dependency checks...
[✓] Checking for dhcpcd5
[✓] Checking for git
[✓] Checking for iproute2
[✓] Checking for whiptail
SELinux not detected
Using interface: eth0
Using upstream DNS: Quad9 (unfiltered, no DNSSEC) (9.9.9.10, 149.112.112.10)
Static IP already configured
Unable to find IPv6 ULA/GUA address, IPv6 adblocking will not be enabled
[i] IPv4 address: 10.0.10.82/24
[i] IPv6 address:
[i] Web Interface On
[i] Web Server On
[i] Logging On.
[✓] Check for existing repository in /etc/.pihole
[i] Update repo in /etc/.pihole...HEAD is now at 4d25f69 Merge pull request #3321 from pi-hole/release/v5.0
[✓] Update repo in /etc/.pihole
[✓] Check for existing repository in /var/www/html/admin
[i] Update repo in /var/www/html/admin...HEAD is now at b86e4a3 Merge pull request #1247 from pi-hole/release/v5.0
[✓] Update repo in /var/www/html/admin
[i] Main Dependency checks...
[✓] Checking for cron
[✓] Checking for curl
[✓] Checking for dnsutils
[✓] Checking for iputils-ping
[✓] Checking for lsof
[✓] Checking for netcat
[✓] Checking for psmisc
[✓] Checking for sudo
[✓] Checking for unzip
[✓] Checking for wget
[✓] Checking for idn2
[✓] Checking for sqlite3
[✓] Checking for libcap2-bin
[✓] Checking for dns-root-data
[✓] Checking for libcap2
[✓] Checking for lighttpd
[✓] Checking for php7.4-common
[✓] Checking for php7.4-cgi
[✓] Checking for php7.4-sqlite3
[✓] Checking for php7.4-xml
[✓] Checking for php-intl
[✓] Enabling lighttpd service to start on reboot...
[i] Creating user 'pihole'...useradd: group pihole exists - if you want to add this user to that group, use -g.
[✗] Creating user 'pihole'
[i] FTL Checks...
[✓] Detected ARM-aarch64 architecture
[i] Checking for existing FTL binary...
[i] Latest FTL Binary already installed (v5.0). Confirming Checksum...
[i] Checksum correct. No need to download!
usermod: user 'pihole' does not exist
grep: /etc/pihole/setupVars.conf: No such file or directory
[i] Testing if systemd-resolved is enabled
[i] Systemd-resolved does not need to be restarted
[i] Restarting lighttpd service...ubuntu@ubuntu-server:~$ ^C
ubuntu@ubuntu-server:~$*
```

Comment: Thank You Skynet !
I will be more careful with editing in future...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem has been finally SOLVED:**

*Steps before even starting:*

```
sudo pihole uninstall
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt purge lighttpd
sudo pihole -r 

useradd -G pihole pihole

sudo apt-get install gamin
```

**Crucial package**, required to install ....
Which was actually missing in my case is :
***apt-get install gamin***

This is/was also well covered at:  [Lighttpd](https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/lighttpd-does-not-start/6207/11)

Before final installation..do a general reboot
(I just did complete power restart)

And after that You are ready to install Pi-hole using command below:
(if You are lucky and no additional "bugs"...)

**`curl -sSL install.pi-hole.net | sudo bash`**

Comment: For me pihole just stopped working for some reason lighttpd couldn't start anymore. **Purging** lighttpd and `$ pihole -r` fixed the issue. Thanks!